# Using PHP preg_match for date Data Type

Tags: pattern-matching, match

Using below pattern matching using preg_match in PHP

if(preg_match('/^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}$/', $dateVar )
{
     Do Something
}

This matches 04/22/2002 but not 4/22/2002
As above pattern is only matching 2 characters for MM and DD from 0-9.

Can any one please suggest to how to match 1-2 characters using preg_match for MM and DD pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below one

```
$dateVar = '4/22/2002'; //4/22/2002

if(preg_match('/^[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{4}$/', $dateVar, $match )){
    print_r($match);
}

output-
Array
(
    [0] => 4/22/2002
)
```